# Sleep function before smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

How can I add a 3 seconds pause before the smooth scroll?
The user will click on the button, then there will be a sleep of 3 seconds and then the smooth scroll will run.

```
 $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please use code block, not quote block for the sample code in your post. Thanks

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { ...your animate code here... }, 3000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an setTimeout() like so:

```
 $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
        }, 3000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JavaScript-standard [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) function:

**JavaScript**

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // function that is executed after the timer ends
}, 3000);
```

As you can see, the `setTimeout` function takes two parameters: a handler (function) that will be executed after the timer ends, and an integer, that defines the timer duration in milliseconds.

If you are unfamiliar with all this "handling" concept, consider the below example instead, where we do the same, but first **"save" the function in a variable**:

**JavaScript**

```
var fnCallback = function () {
    console.log('This plague works.');
};

// Call setTimeout() with a handler function (fnCallback), and an integer (3000)
setTimeout(fnCallback, 3000);
```